# CSS -> Hover effect dosen't work

Tags: html, css, browser, hover, effect

My CSS Code don't detect, if my cursor over the div: But if i active "hover" with the browser developer tool, it works.

Explain: The Div shows, if I go over a button, but the div hide out, if i go out of the button...

My code:

```css
.profilanzeige2 {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  top: -250px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  /* border: 1px solid #797979; */
  background-image: none;
  background: #16b751;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #16b751 0%, #19ad46 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #16b751 0%,#19ad4619ad46 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #16b751 0%,#19ad46 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#16b751', endColorstr='#19ad46',GradientType=0 );
  transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

#profilanzeige:hover ~ #profilanzeige2, .profilanzeige2:hover {
    top: 54px !important;
}

#profilanzeige:hover + #profilanzeige2, .profilanzeige2:hover {
    top: 54px !important;
}

.profil:hover ~ #profilanzeige2, #profilanzeige2:hover {
    top: 54px !important;
}

.profil:hover + #profilanzeige2, #profilanzeige2:hover {
    top: 54px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="profilanzeige2" id="profilanzeige2">
        <img src="https://ftimg.de/images/2017/03/02/5e2c4f6af5024d26bb95d074a3ed9a86.png">

        <p class="profil-name"><?php echo $user['icname']; ?></p>


        <a href="profil.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="Profilanzeigen">
          Profil anzeigen
        </button></a>

        <a href="logout.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="Abmelden" href="logout.php">
          Abmelden
        </button></a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
<div class="profilanzeige2" id="profilanzeige2">
```

with class *profilanzeige***2** but the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) is on #*profilanzeige*

Another thing which could be improved, for the sake of readability, is to have different names of the class and the id in the div.

Comment: <div class='navbar-header profilanzeige' id='profilanzeige'> This is right, i want; that the profil shows when you over "#profilanzeige" and over "#profilanzeige2"

Answer (score 0):

Fixxed, i had z-index on -1. I change it to over 0 and all work fine.